# Open classic form on modern list when clicking the New button

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, modern-experience, classic-experience

Can someone help me understand how I can do that?

We have this behaviour on a site in our tenant. I not able to reproduce on another site.

This article mention that I can set the ContentType.EditFormUrl or ContentType.NewFormUrl properties to point to a custom form URL and that should work. When are those properties I don't understand.

[https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/differences-between-modern-and-classic-experiences-for-lists-and-libraries-30e1aab0-a5cc-4363-b7f2-09e2ae07d4dc?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#:~:text=1.%C2%A0%20Set%20the%20ContentType.EditFormUrl%20or%20ContentType.NewFormUrl%20properties%20to%20point%20to%20a%20custom%20form%20URL%C2%A0](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/differences-between-modern-and-classic-experiences-for-lists-and-libraries-30e1aab0-a5cc-4363-b7f2-09e2ae07d4dc?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#:%7E:text=1.%C2%A0%20Set%20the%20ContentType.EditFormUrl%20or%20ContentType.NewFormUrl%20properties%20to%20point%20to%20a%20custom%20form%20URL%C2%A0)

This issue also talk about it:
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/6157

I'd appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

So there is nowhere in the user interface of SharePoint online to set ContentType.EditFormUrl or ContentType.NewFormUrl... Powershell is our friend.

```
$webUrl = "https://**********.sharepoint.com/sites/**********"  
  
$listName = "**********"  

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $webUrl –UseWebLogin
$context = Get-PnPContext

$web = $context.web
$context.load($web)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

$list = $web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName)  
$context.load($list)
$context.ExecuteQuery()  

$contentTypes=$list.ContentTypes
$context.load($contentTypes) 
$context.ExecuteQuery() 

$contentType=$contentTypes[0]
$contentType.NewFormUrl="/**********/NewForm.aspx"  
$contentType.update($false)  
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```